# Assign an object to a BindableProperty in ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try to initialize and assign an instance of a custom class to a `BindableProperty` in a `ResourceDictionary` (styles.xaml).

My class:

```cs
namespace Foo {
  public class Colors {
    public Color Positive { get; set; }
    public Color Negative { get; set; }
    public Color Neutral { get; set; }

    public Colors() { }
  }
}
```

My class with BindableProperty:

```cs
namespace Foo {
  public class Bar : ContentView {
    public Colors Colors {
      get => (Colors)GetValue(ColorsProperty);
      set => SetValue(ColorsProperty, value);
    }

   public static BindableProperty ColorsProperty = 
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Colors), typeof(Colors), 
            typeof(Bar), null, BindingMode.OneWay);
```

styles.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:Foo;assembly=Foo">
  <foo:Colors
        x:Key="colors"
        Positive="Green"
        Negative="Red"
        Neutral="Blue"/>

  ...

  <Style TargetType="foo:Bar">
    <Setter Property="Colors" Value="{StaticResource colors}"/>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

A breakpoint in the constructor of class `Foo.Colors` is hit, so an instance of this class is created during loading styles.xaml. However loading styles.xaml crashes with an unhandled `NullReferenceException` inside Mono.Android.
When i delete the assignment of the Color-Property everything works fine, so the assignment must be the problem.

Any suggestions?

Exception Details:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception (System.Exception e) [0x0000e] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x0001d] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:111 
  at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

The Exception occures in App.xaml.g.cs, after `global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(App));`

Comment: Exception details would be nice

Comment: You may try to change "Property="Colors"" to"Property="foo:Bar.Colors"". For more information about XAML resource references, you may refer to the website："https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/attached-properties".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution that works for me:

In styles.xaml I replaced `StaticResource` with `DynamicResource`:

```xml
<Style TargetType="foo:Bar">
  <Setter Property="Colors" Value="{DynamicResource colors}"/>
</Style>
```

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting to use a stand-alone resource dictionary. I've had trouble with these in the past when I've followed Microsofts documentation on them. I've always had to set the dictionary as if it's in [another assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merge-resource-dictionaries-from-other-assemblies):

styles.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:DELETEME"
    x:Class="DELETEME.styles">

    <foo:Colors
        x:Key="colors"
        Positive="Green"
        Negative="Red"
        Neutral="Blue"/>

    <Style TargetType="foo:Bar">
        <Setter Property="Colors" Value="{StaticResource colors}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Note that this file does require a simple code behind:

```
namespace DELETEME
{
    public partial class styles : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public styles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The easiest way to add this file is add a ContentView with xaml, then change the xaml and cs to inherit from ResourceDictionary.

From there, add the file to the merged dictionaries of the app or page:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:DELETEME"
         x:Class="DELETEME.App">

    <Application.Resources>
       <ResourceDictionary>
           <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <foo:styles />
           </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This should resolve your errors. Example below.

Bar.cs class:

```
public class Bar : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Colors), typeof(Colors), typeof(Bar));

    public Colors Colors
    {
        get => (Colors)GetValue(ColorsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ColorsProperty, value);
    }

    public Bar()
    {
        var b1 = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Colors.Negative };
        var b2 = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Colors.Neutral };
        var b3 = new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Colors.Positive };

        var sl = new StackLayout();

        sl.Children.Add(b1);
        sl.Children.Add(b2);
        sl.Children.Add(b3);

        Content = sl;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml class:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:foo="clr-namespace:DELETEME"
         x:Class="DELETEME.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <foo:Bar />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Running Result:

[image]